# How to handle SSH failures in Expect script

Tags: loops, scripting, automation, tcl, expect

I have an expect script that logs in to a list of devices and run a series of commands.
Everything works fine except when one of the hosts is/becomes unreachable and the script just exits. Is there a way to get it to skip the unreachable host & move on to the remaining devices?

Here's the main body of my script.

```
foreach host $hosts {
    spawn -noecho /usr/bin/ssh user@$host
    set timeout 10
    expect {
        "assword:"              { send [string trimright "$pwd" "\r"]   }
        "No route*"             {puts "Host error -> $expect_out(buffer)";exit}
        "Could not resolve*"    {puts "Host error -> $expect_out(buffer)";exit}
    }
    expect "#"
    send "term len 0\r"
    expect "#"
    send "show version\r"
    expect "#"
    send "exit\r"
    expect eof
}
```

And here's what i get:

```
.
. <output of reachable device - R1> 
.
Connection to R1 closed by remote host.
Connection to R1 closed.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname R2: Name or service not known
Host error -> ssh: Could not resolve hostname R1: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Expect is, essentially, an extension to the TCL language, your question really boils down to "how to I end a loop iteration early in TCL?".

The answer is, use the `continue` command instead of the `exit` command.

Comment: That dit it! Thanks a lot :)